# How to add image depending on what result or emotion it might detect

Tags: java, android, android-layout, azure-cognitive-services

I have been trying to figure this out all day, as I would like to add an image depending on the outcome of the emotion may detect. Just wanted to add some some images but I'm still new to this. Can anyone help me with this one to.

btw here's my code:

```
  public class DetectionActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    // Background task of face detection.
    private class DetectionTask extends AsyncTask<InputStream, String, Face[]> {
        private boolean mSucceed = true;

        @Override
        protected Face[] doInBackground(InputStream... params) {
            // Get an instance of face service client to detect faces in image.
            FaceServiceClient faceServiceClient = SampleApp.getFaceServiceClient();
            try {
                publishProgress("Detecting...");

                // Start detection.
                return faceServiceClient.detect(
                        params[0],  /* Input stream of image to detect */
                        true,       /* Whether to return face ID */
                        true,       /* Whether to return face landmarks */
                 
                        new FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType[]{
                                
                                FaceServiceClient.FaceAttributeType.Emotion,
                              
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                mSucceed = false;
                publishProgress(e.getMessage());
                addLog(e.getMessage());
                return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            mProgressDialog.show();
            addLog("Request: Detecting in image " + mImageUri);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
            mProgressDialog.setMessage(progress[0]);
            setInfo(progress[0]);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Face[] result) {
            if (mSucceed) {
                addLog("Response: Success. Detected " + (result == null ? 0 : result.length)
                        + " face(s) in " + mImageUri);
            }

            // Show the result on screen when detection is done.
            setUiAfterDetection(result, mSucceed);
        }
    }

    // Flag to indicate which task is to be performed.
    private static final int REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE = 0;

    // The URI of the image selected to detect.
    private Uri mImageUri;

    // The image selected to detect.
    private Bitmap mBitmap;

    // Progress dialog popped up when communicating with server.
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    // When the activity is created, set all the member variables to initial state.
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detection);
        //this hides the back button and I thank you
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle(getString(R.string.progress_dialog_title));

        // Disable button "detect" as the image to detect is not selected.
        setDetectButtonEnabledStatus(false);

        LogHelper.clearDetectionLog();


    }

    // Save the activity state when it's going to stop.
    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putParcelable("ImageUri", mImageUri);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menuAbout:
                // Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked about", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                View messageView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.about, null, false);

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builder.setIcon(R.drawable.smile);
                builder.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
                builder.setView(messageView);
                builder.create();
                builder.show();
                break;

            case R.id.menuHelp:
                // Toast.makeText(this, "You clicked settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                //  Intent help = new Intent(this, HelpActivity.class);
                //startActivity(help);
                // break;
                View messageViewh = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.help, null, false);

                AlertDialog.Builder builderh = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
                builderh.setIcon(R.drawable.smile);
                builderh.setTitle(R.string.app_nameh);
                builderh.setView(messageViewh);
                builderh.create();
                builderh.show();
                break;

        }
        return true;
    }


    // Recover the saved state when the activity is recreated.
    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        mImageUri = savedInstanceState.getParcelable("ImageUri");
        if (mImageUri != null) {
            mBitmap = ImageHelper.loadSizeLimitedBitmapFromUri(
                    mImageUri, getContentResolver());
        }
    }

    // Called when image selection is done.
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE:
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    // If image is selected successfully, set the image URI and bitmap.
                    mImageUri = data.getData();
                    mBitmap = ImageHelper.loadSizeLimitedBitmapFromUri(
                            mImageUri, getContentResolver());
                    if (mBitmap != null) {
                        // Show the image on screen.
                        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                        imageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);

                        // Add detection log.
                        addLog("Image: " + mImageUri + " resized to " + mBitmap.getWidth()
                                + "x" + mBitmap.getHeight());
                    }

                    // Clear the detection result.
                    FaceListAdapter faceListAdapter = new FaceListAdapter(null);
                    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_detected_faces);
                    listView.setAdapter(faceListAdapter);

                    // Clear the information panel.
                    setInfo("");

                    // Enable button "detect" as the image is selected and not detected.
                    setDetectButtonEnabledStatus(true);
                }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    // Called when the "Select Image" button is clicked.
    public void selectImage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SelectImageActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_SELECT_IMAGE);
    }

    // Called when the "Detect" button is clicked.
    public void detect(View view) {
        // Put the image into an input stream for detection.
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(output.toByteArray());

        // Start a background task to detect faces in the image.
        new DetectionTask().execute(inputStream);

        // Prevent button click during detecting.
        setAllButtonsEnabledStatus(false);
    }

    // View the log of service calls.
    public void viewLog(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DetectionLogActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    // Show the result on screen when detection is done.
    private void setUiAfterDetection(Face[] result, boolean succeed) {
        // Detection is done, hide the progress dialog.
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();

        // Enable all the buttons.
        setAllButtonsEnabledStatus(true);

        // Disable button "detect" as the image has already been detected.
        setDetectButtonEnabledStatus(false);

        if (succeed) {
            // The information about the detection result.
            String detectionResult;
            if (result != null) {
                detectionResult = result.length + " face"
                        + (result.length != 1 ? "s" : "") + " detected";

                // Show the detected faces on original image.
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(ImageHelper.drawFaceRectanglesOnBitmap(
                        mBitmap, result, true));

                // Set the adapter of the ListView which contains the details of the detected faces.
                FaceListAdapter faceListAdapter = new FaceListAdapter(result);

                // Show the detailed list of detected faces.
                ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_detected_faces);
                listView.setAdapter(faceListAdapter);
            } else {
                detectionResult = "0 face detected";
            }
            setInfo(detectionResult);
        }

        mImageUri = null;
        mBitmap = null;
    }

    // Set whether the buttons are enabled.
    private void setDetectButtonEnabledStatus(boolean isEnabled) {
        Button detectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detect);
        detectButton.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    // Set whether the buttons are enabled.
    private void setAllButtonsEnabledStatus(boolean isEnabled) {
        Button selectImageButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.select_image);
        selectImageButton.setEnabled(isEnabled);

        Button detectButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.detect);
        detectButton.setEnabled(isEnabled);

     //   Button ViewLogButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.view_log);
       // ViewLogButton.setEnabled(isEnabled);
    }

    // Set the information panel on screen.
    private void setInfo(String info) {
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
        textView.setText(info);
    }

    // Add a log item.
    private void addLog(String log) {
        LogHelper.addDetectionLog(log);
    }

    // The adapter of the GridView which contains the details of the detected faces.
    private class FaceListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        // The detected faces.
        List<Face> faces;

        // The thumbnails of detected faces.
        List<Bitmap> faceThumbnails;

        // Initialize with detection result.
        FaceListAdapter(Face[] detectionResult) {
            faces = new ArrayList<>();
            faceThumbnails = new ArrayList<>();

            if (detectionResult != null) {
                faces = Arrays.asList(detectionResult);
                for (Face face : faces) {
                    try {
                        // Crop face thumbnail with five main landmarks drawn from original image.
                        faceThumbnails.add(ImageHelper.generateFaceThumbnail(
                                mBitmap, face.faceRectangle));
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // Show the exception when generating face thumbnail fails.
                        setInfo(e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isEnabled(int position) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return faces.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return faces.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater layoutInflater =
                        (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_face_with_description, parent, false);
            }
            convertView.setId(position);

            // Show the face thumbnail.
            ((ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.face_thumbnail)).setImageBitmap(
                    faceThumbnails.get(position));

            // Show the face details.
            String getEmotion;
           // String improve = improveMessage(getEmotion);
            DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#0.0");
            //add
            //  String message = findMessage(getEmotion());

           // String improve = improveMessage(getEmotion);
            String face_description = String.format("Emotion: %s\n",
                   
                    getEmotion(faces.get(position).faceAttributes.emotion)
                   
            );
            ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text_detected_face)).setText(face_description);

            return convertView;
        }

        private String getEmotion(Emotion emotion) {
            String emotionType = "";
            double emotionValue = 0.0;
            String emotionInfo = "";
            if (emotion.anger > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.anger;
                emotionType = "Anger";
                
                emotionInfo = "If you haven't fed him/her yet maybe this precious one is thirsty or hungry.\n Try giving your attention. If your baby is acting unusual it's best to seek for medical help.";
            }
            if (emotion.contempt > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.contempt;
                emotionType = "Contempt";
                emotionInfo = "You go girl!";
            }
            if (emotion.disgust > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.disgust;
                emotionType = "Disgust";
                emotionInfo = "Look! If your baby is feeling this way mabye she/he doesn't like this. \n If what your doing right now is good for him/her maybe you can support that.";
            }
            if (emotion.fear > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.fear;
                emotionType = "Fear";
                emotionInfo = "Your baby looks somewhat uncomfortable.\n Make your baby feel comfortable and take note of what makes them feel like that. ";
            }
            if (emotion.happiness > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.happiness;
                emotionType = "Happiness";
                emotionInfo = "Just continue what you are doing. It is important to remember what can make them happy. \n";
            }
        if (emotion.neutral > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.neutral;
                emotionType = "Neutral";
                emotionInfo = "Maybe you should just observe first";
            }
            if (emotion.sadness > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.sadness;
                emotionType = "Sadness";
                emotionInfo = "Just cuddle or dandle your baby.";
            }
            if (emotion.surprise > emotionValue) {
                emotionValue = emotion.surprise;
                emotionType = "Surprise";
                emotionInfo = "Oooh look. Play with your baby. Try doing peek a boo";
            }
            return String.format("%s: %f \n\n%s", emotionType, emotionValue, emotionInfo);
        }

    }
}
```

Just would like to add some images like happy if that is the detected emotion. Please do help me. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you :)

I would like to add that after the emotionInfo.

Comment: Does my answer useful to you ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess `detectWithStream` is you want.

Official Doc:  [Faces.detectWithStream Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.vision.faceapi.faces.detectwithstream?view=azure-java-stable#com_microsoft_azure_cognitiveservices_vision_faceapi_Faces_detectWithStream__)

From Java SDK, the `List<DetectedFace>` object will return if successful.

[image]